# Add data to Firebase instead of SetValue, in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I want to add data in addition to the current data.
The only way I know is save the current data, add it in my app and then write it to the firebase. But what if 2 people do it in the exact time? The one who did it first - will be forbidden.

So do you know any other way to add data to the Firebase instead of SetValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tackle this simultaneous value updation , **`runTransactionBlocks`** are used

Like this function, lets say this reference is of noOfPost, and all i want to do is increase the value by 1

If two users increase this reference value simutaneously, This request will be uploaded in the separate Thread, and will override the possibility of simultaneous updates in your Database:-

```
func updateTotalNoOfPost(completionBlock : @escaping (() -> Void)){


    let prntRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("_yourNodeRef")

    prntRef.runTransactionBlock({ (returned_Data) -> FIRTransactionResult in
        if let totalPost = returned_Data.value as? Int{
            print(totalPost)
            returned_Data.value = totalPost+1 //Your updated or appended value, or whatever you wanna do with this

            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: returned_Data)
        }else{

            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: returned_Data)

        }
        }, andCompletionBlock: {(error,completion,snap) in

            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            print(completion)
            print(snap)
            if !completion {

                print("The value wasn't able to Update")
            }else{

                completionBlock()
            }
    })

}
```

Calling the function:-

```
 updateTotalNoOfPost{
      print("The value was updated")
    }
```

Comment: How do I call the function?